# no need to delete struct memory in vector<StructA*>?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, vector

i saw some code like below, but i didn't see any delete statement, is there any memory leak problem?

```
struct RStatus
{
    int fid;
    int status;
};

void Foo()
{
    vector<RStatus*> rsVec;

    RStatus* rs = null;
    rs = new RStatus(); // memory allocated here!
    rs->fid = 0
    rs->status = 0;
    rsVec.push_back(rs);

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use `vector<RStatus*>`, then you have to use `delete`, otherwise you will have a memory leak.

However, if you use `vector<RStatus>`, then you don't have to use `delete` — this is recommended<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1. If you want to use pointers, then the recommendation is that you should be using smart pointers such as `std::unique_ptr`, or `std::shared_ptr`.</sup>

Comment: std::shared_ptr does this needs *delete*?

Comment: @Scott混合理论: Yes, `shared_ptr` takes care of `delete`. You don't need to worry about that anymore.

Comment: *"If you use vector<RStatus*>, then you have to use delete"* -- Only if you are allocating with `new` of course.  If you are using pointers as nullable/reassignable references (one of their few remaining uses), then you don't delete.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: That is true but I don't want to make my answer complex by adding all the traps and pitfalls. It usually confuses/demotivates the new learners.

Comment: In this case, any solution involving pointers is just wrong.  `RStatus` clearly has value semantics, and is cheap to copy; allocating it dynamically is bad practice, regardless of where it occurs and what one does with the pointer afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should free your memory allocated :

```
struct RStatus
{
    int fid;
    int status;
};

void Foo()
{
    vector<RStatus*> rsVec;

    RStatus* rs = null;
    rs = new RStatus(); // memory allocated here!
    rs->fid = 0
    rs->status = 0;
    rsVec.push_back(rs);


    // free :
    unsigned int size = rsVec.size();
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
        delete rsVec[i];     // delete because you used new
}
```

If you don't do that, all the memory will never be released at the vector destruction.

I would suggest you to use `std::vector<RStatus>` instead of `std::vector<RStatus*>`.

You may also used smart ptr. You can found some documentation about it here : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/

**EDIT:** As suggested in comments, if an exception is thrown at `rsVec.push_back(rs)`, the memory allocated will be lost, that's why smart pointers would be a better solution. Or again, use `std::vector<RStatus>` instead.

Comment: It'll also be lost if `rsVec.push_back(rs);` throws. One of the reasons raw pointer are frowned upon is that it is difficult to write exception safe code in cases like this. RAII (smart pointers) > raw resources.

Comment: I'm just adding to it, not critizing :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a memory leak: the pointer to the created structure is lost after the vector is destroyed, and the memory is never released.

Unless someone performs a `delete` for each element of `rsVec` before clearing or destroying the vector.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that code leaks the `RStatus`.

It also does nothing else: possibly the real code's `vector` gets passed to some function that takes posession of the `vector`'s contents.

Tracking down memory leaks is generally not a local problem: every use of that pointer has to, in theory, be examine to figure out if it leaks.  Techniques like 'if I allocate it, delete it' and RAII (including smart pointers) attempt to make it more local, so you can tell from an incomplete program if there is a leak.

Answer (score 0):

use `boost::shared_ptr` if you don't want to bother yourself with a deletion of allocated objects.
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm

```
struct RStatus
{
    int fid;
    int status;
};

void Foo()
{
    vector<shared_ptr<RStatus> > rsVec;

    shared_ptr<RStatus> rs = shared_ptr<RStatus>(); // empty shared_ptr
    rs.reset(new RStatus()); // memory allocated here!
    rs->fid = 0
    rs->status = 0;
    rsVec.push_back(rs); // shared_ptr is copied

}// vector is destroyed and shared_ptrs also
```

be careful however not to mixed up things using both `shared_ptr` and ordinary, raw pointers to avoid situation when `shared_ptr` tries to delete object which is already deleted